# In what scenario would React stateful component be required over a functional component using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stateless, stateful, react-functional-component

React appears to be able to handle all of the component lifecycle methods in a functional component with useEffect hook.
And there is a setState hook for managing state.

I'm trying to ask... **When you would you still need to use a stateful component?**
If a functional component can do everything a stateful component can with hooks.

Or maybe a better way to word it is
**Is there any condition where a stateful component would be required... such that a functional component with hooks would not work?**

ADMINS PLEASE HELP ME OUT HERE (not sure how to word this -- feel free to clean it up)

Comment: *stateful component* is a misnomer. You're referring to a *class* component. A functional component can be *stateful*. All *stateful* means is that it has state. `useState` is state, therefore if a functional component uses `useState` it is *stateful*. Inversely, if a *class* component does not use state, it is *stateless*.

Comment: You should always prefer to use functional components over class components, you can see here the reasons why Facebook is pushing towards that https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation

Comment: A follow-up question is, why are you even asking this? If you are thinking about why `class` components exist, it's for compatibility with legacy code, but that might be dropped one day. Since I started using hooks, I never found a reason to use a `class` component. It was the opposite, `class` components make it more difficult to separate the bulk of the logic or introduce logic which spans through different lifecycle hooks (e.g. mount and update), so I found myself rewriting a lot of  `class` components to function components. So if you do not know why, you do not need `class` components :)

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I wish I had documented where I read or heard ... maybe it was even on React docs. That there are still situations in which one would require a class component. All of the comments are exactly right -- I cannot see why one would choose class component given how restrictive. But is there a reason one would need to keep using (besides legacy)

Comment: @Acts7Seven I’m not aware of any capacity of a class component that cannot be replicated with hooks. I’ve written my fair share of React code since the introduction of hooks and never found myself wanting to have a class component instead. But the opposite was true, there were cases where I wanted to use hooks but couldn’t because it was a class component. As mentioned in the [React hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both), the React team expects hooks to be the primary way of writing React comments.